# How can I write a QuadWord from AVX512 register zmm26 to the rax register?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, avx512

I wish to perform integer arithmetic operations on Quad Word elements of the zmm 0-31 register set and preserve the carry bit resulting from those operations.  It appears this is only possible if the data were worked on in the general register set.

Thus I would like to copy information from one of the zmm 0-31 registers to one of the general purpose registers.  After working on the 64 bit data in the general purpose register, I would like to return the data to the original zmm 0-31 register in the same QuadWord location it came from.  I know that I can move the data from the general purpose register rax to the AVX512 register zmm26 QuadWord location 5 using the command

```
    vpbroadcastq zmm26{k5}{z},rax
```

where 8 bit mask k5 = decimal 32, allows broadcasting of the data to the 5th QuadWord of zmm26 and z=1 indicating that no other QWord in zmm26 is affected, and rax is where the data originates from.

But I cannot find an inverse command that will write the data from register zmm26, Quad word 5 to the rax register. It appears that I can only copy the least significant QuadWord from an AVX register to a general purpose register using the vmovq rax, xmm1 command. And there is no broadcast command using a masked zmm 0-31 source.

I would appreciate knowing what my command options would be to get a particular QuadWord from an zmm 0-31 register to the rax register would be.  Also, are there any other descriptive sources of information on the AVX512 instruction set other than the intel manual at this point?

Comment: You can emulate carry-handling in vector regs by doing a compare afterwards.  (e.g. unsigned `a+b < a` means carry happened, and AVX512F has an unsigned-less-than predicate for integer compare instructions like [`vcmpq`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPCMPQ_VPCMPUQ.html)).  Sometimes this is better than unpacking to integer.  Especially if you need to do it for all elements in a ZMM vector.

Comment: Related: going the other direction with AVX512 or AVX2 [How to move double in %rax into particular qword position on %ymm or %zmm? (Kaby Lake or later)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52309909).  And [Move an int64\_t to the high quadwords of an AVX2 \_\_m256i vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54048226) for C intrinsics for AVX2.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike some of the earlier SIMD extensions which had the "extract" instructions such as `pextrq` which would do this directly, I'm not aware of any way to do it in AVX-512 (nor in AVX with ymm registers) other than:

1. Permuting/shuffling the element you want into the lower order quadword and then using `vmovq` as you noted to get it into a general purpose register.
2. Storing the entire vector to a temporary memory location `loc`, such as the stack, then using `mov register,[loc + offset]` instructions to read whichever qword(s) you are interested in.

Both approaches seem pretty ugly, and which is better depends on your exact scenario. Despite using memory as an intermediary, the second approach may be faster if you plan to extract several values from each vector since you can make use of both load ports on recent CPUs which have throughput of one load/cycle, while the permute/shuffle approach is likely to bottleneck a on the port required for the permute/shuffle.

See Peter's answer below for a more comprehensive treatment, including using the `vcompress` instructions with a mask as a kind of poor-man's extract.

Comment: While it's hard to guess at the performance of future processors, I'm gonna try anyway and suggest `vextracti32x4` followed by `vpextrq`. This one doesn't need a permute vector.

Comment: That makes sense. I often use PSHUFB as my hammer since it effectively offers a superset of most of the other permute and broadcast instructions, as well as the best latency of 1 cycle, so in some way it almost obsoletes the other more constrained instructions. However, when it works, using one of the constrained instructions is often still better since you don't have to set up the shuffle mask, you save a register, and in some cases your instruction can execute one a wider variety of ports.

Comment: `vpcompressq zmm1{k5}, zmm26`  is almost an inverse of the OP's hack, but with a vector or memory destination.  Not as fast as a single shuffle, though.,

Answer (score 2):

[`vpbroadcastq zmm26{k5}{z},rax`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPBROADCASTB_W_D_Q.html) is an interesting hack; could be useful if it runs efficiently.  Especially with merge-masking as an alternative to `vmovq` / [`vpinsrq`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/PINSRB_PINSRD_PINSRQ.html).

There is no single-instruction inverse to this (ab)use of `vpbroadcastq`, except for elements 0 or 1:  [`vmovq rax, xmm26`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/MOVD_MOVQ.html) or [`vpextrq rax, xmm26, 1`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/PEXTRB_PEXTRD_PEXTRQ.html).  Yes, there are EVEX encodings for those instructions that let them access xmm16-31, in AVX512F and AVX512DQ respectively.  If your data is in xmm0-15, you can use the shorter VEX-encoded version.

However, **you could abuse [`VPCOMPRESSQ zmm1/m512 {k5}{z}, zmm26`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPCOMPRESSQ.html)** to do what you want with a memory or zmm destination, using the same single-set-bit mask register that you used for `vpbroadcast`.  But it's not as fast as other options, so the only advantage is using the same mask-register as a shuffle control, saving work if you can't hoist setup out of a loop.

On KNL, `VPCOMPRESSQ` (with a register destination) has one per 3 cycle throughput (according to [Agner Fog](http://agner.org/optimize/)'s testing).  [On Skylake-AVX512](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeX_InstLatX64.txt), it's one per 2 cycles, with 3c latency.  Both of those CPUs run `vpermq` at 1 per cycle, so it probably causes less interference with other instructions.  I haven't found timings for the memory-destination version of `vpcompressq`.

---

Going the other direction without a store/reload requires at least one shuffle uop, and a separate uop to copy from vector to GP register (like `vmovq`).    (If you eventually want all the elements, a store/reload is probably better than a pure ALU strategy.  ALU for the first one or two is probably good, so you have them with low latency so some dependent operations can get started).

**If your value is in the low 64b of a 128b "lane"** (i.e. an even-numbered element), then [`vextracti64x2 xmm1, zmm26, 3`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VEXTRACTI128_VEXTRACTI32x4_VEXTRACTI64x2_VEXTRACTI32x8_VEXTRACTI64x4.html) / `vmovq rax, xmm1` is about as efficient as possible for a single element.  The weird name is because the AVX512 version of `vextracti128` comes in two flavours of masking granularity.  If the element you want is in the 2nd 128b lane of zmm0-15, you can save code-size by using `vextracti128 xmm1, ymm6, 1` (only a 3-byte VEX prefix for the AVX2 instruction, not 4-byte EVEX).

But if your value is in the upper 64b of a lane (i.e. an odd-numbered element, counting from 0), you'd need, `vpextrq rax, xmm, 1` instead of `vmovq`, and it decodes (on Skylake) to a shuffle uop and a `vmovq` uop.  (Never use `vpextrq rax, xmm, 0`, because it wastes a shuffle uop.  This is why compilers optimize `_mm_extract_epi64(v, 0)` to a `vmovq`.)

**For an odd numbered element, you can still do it in one shuffle with `vpermq zmm1, zmm2, zmm3/m512/m64bcst` + `vmovq`**.  If you need to extract in a loop, setting up a shuffle vector constant outside the loop.  Or if you need other constants anyway (so there's already a hot cache-line of constants for your function), a broadcast-load memory operand should be fine if not in a loop.

**`vpermq` + `vmovq` also works when the index is not a compile-time constant**, since all you need in a shuffle control vector is to have the index in element 0.  e.g. `vmovd xmm7, ecx` sets you up for `vpermq zmm1, zmm2, zmm7` / `vmovq rax, zxm1`

---

As @Bee says, store/reload is a good option if you need more than one element.  You could also use it if you need a runtime-variable element, since store-forwarding from an aligned 512b store to an aligned 64b reload probably works without stalling.  (Still higher latency than the `vpermq` solution, but uses only memory uops, not ALU.  ALU uops may be at a premium in Skylake-AVX512, where port1 won't run any vector uops while there are 512b uops running.)

If your element number is a compile-time constant, you could store only the required 128b lane of the ZMM vector to memory, using `vextracti64x2 [rsp-16], zmm26, 3`.  (Or `vextracti128` if it's lane 1.)  If you want the value in memory eventually anyway, you could use a mask register with only the 2nd bit set to store just the high element.  (But IDK how well that performs if the masked part of the extra goes to an unmapped page.  IIRC, it doesn't actually fault, but microarchitecturally it may be slow to handle that.  Even crossing a cache-line boundary with the 128b full width could be slow.)

The AVX2 `VEXTRACTI128 [mem], ymm, 1` instruction runs on Skylake as just a (non-micro-fused) store, with no shuffle port (http://agner.org/optimize/).  AVX512 extract-to-memory is hopefully the same, still not using a shuffle uop.  ([Throughput / latency Instlatx64 numbers are available](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeX_InstLatX64.txt), but we don't know what competes with what for which throughput resources, so it's a lot less useful than Agner Fog's instruction tables.)

For KNL, `VEXTRACTF32X4 [mem], zmm` is 4 uops, with bad throughput, and AVX2 `vextracti128 [mem], ymm, imm8` is the same.  So (assuming store-forwarding works well) just store the whole 512b vector on KNL.