# How to move double in %rax into particular qword position on %ymm or %zmm? (Kaby Lake or later)

Tags: c++, x86-64, inline-assembly, intrinsics, avx

The idea is that I'd like to collect returned values of `double` into a vector register for processing for machine `imm width` at a time ***without*** storing back into memory first.

The particular processing is a `vfma` with other two operands that are all `constexpr`, so that they can simply be summoned by `_mm256_setr_pd` or aligned/unaligned memory load from `constexpr` `array`.

Is there a way to store double in `%ymm` at particular position directly from value in `%rax` for collecting purpose?

The target machine is Kaby Lake. More efficient of future vector instructions are welcome also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline-assembly is usually a bad idea: modern compilers do a good job with x86 intrinsics.

Putting the bit-pattern for a `double` into RAX is usually also not useful, and smells like you've probably already gone down the wrong path into sub-optimal territory.  Vector shuffle instructions are usually better: element-wise insert/extract instructions already cost a shuffle uop on Intel hardware, except for `vmovq %xmm0, %rax` to get the low element.

Also, if you're going to insert it into another vector, you should shuffle/immediate-blend.  (`vpermpd` / `vblendpd`).

L1d and store-forwarding cache is fast, and even store-forwarding stalls are not a disaster.  Choose wisely between ALU vs. memory to gather or scatter of data into / from SIMD vectors.  Also remember that insert/extract instructions need an immediate index, so if you have a runtime index for a vector, you definitely want to store it and index.  (See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other performance links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Lots of insert/extract can quickly bottleneck on port 5 on Haswell and later.  **See [Loading an xmm from GP regs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779309/loading-an-xmm-from-gp-regs)** for more details, and some links to gcc bug reports where I went into more detail about strategies for different element widths on different uarches and with SSE4.1 vs. without SSE4.1, etc.

---

There's no PD version of [`extractps r/m32, xmm, imm`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/EXTRACTPS.html), and `insertps` is a shuffle between XMM vectors.

**To read/write the low lane of a YMM, you'll have to use integer `vpextrq $1, %xmm0, %rax` / `pinsrq $1, %rax, %xmm0`**.  Those aren't available in YMM width, so you need multiple instructions to read/write the high lane.

The VEX version `vpinsrq $1, %rax, %xmm0` will zero the high lane(s) of the destination vector's full YMM or ZMM width, which is why I suggested `pinsrq`.  On Skylake and later, it won't cause an SSE/AVX transition stall.  See [Using ymm registers as a "memory-like" storage location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915381/using-ymm-registers-as-a-memory-like-storage-location) for an example (NASM syntax), and also **[Loading an xmm from GP regs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779309/loading-an-xmm-from-gp-regs)**

**For the low element, use `vmovq %xmm0, %rax`** to extract, it's cheaper than `vpextrq` (1 uop instead of 2).

---

**For ZMM**, my answer on that linked XMM from GP regs question shows that you can use AVX512F to merge-mask an integer register into a vector, given a mask register with a single bit set.

```
vpbroadcastq %rax, %zmm0{%k1}
```

Similarly, `vpcompressq` can move an element selected by a single-bit mask to the bottom for `vmovq`.

**But for extract, if have an index instead of `1<<index` to start with**, you may be better off with **`vmovd %ecx, %zmm1` / `vpermd %zmm0, %zmm1, %zmm2`** / `vmovq %zmm2, %rax`.  This trick even works with `vpshufb` for byte elements (with a lane at least).  For lane crossing, maybe shuffle + `vmovd` with the high bits of the byte index, then scalar right-shift using the low bits of the index as the byte-within-word offset.  See also [How to use _mm_extract_epi8 function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492956/how-to-use-mm-extract-epi8-function/54494663#54494663) for intrinsics for a variable-index emulation of `pextrb`.

---

### High lane of a YMM, with AVX2

I think your best bet to write an element in the high lane of a YMM with AVX2 needs a scratch register:

- `vmovq %rax, %xmm0` (copy to a scratch vector)
- shuffle into position with `vinsertf128` (AVX1) or `vpbroadcastq`/`vbroadcastsd`.  it's faster than `vpermq`/`vpermpd` on AMD.  (But the reg-reg version is still AVX2-only)
- `vblendpd` (FP) or `vpblendd` (integer) into the target YMM reg.  Immediate blends with dword or larger element width are very cheap (1 uop for any vector ALU port on Intel).

This is only 3 uops, but 2 of them need port 5 on Intel CPUs.  (So it costs the same as a `vpinsrq` + a blend).  Only the blend is on the critical path from vector input to vector output, setting up `ymm0` from `rax` is independent.

To read the highest element, `vpermpd` or `vpermq $3, %ymm1, %ymm0` (AVX2), then `vmovq` from xmm0.

To read the 2nd-highest element, `vextractf128 $1, %ymm1, %xmm0` (AVX1) and `vmovq`.  `vextractf128` is faster than `vpermq/pd` on AMD CPUs.

---

A bad alternative to avoid a scratch reg for insert would be `vpermq` or `vperm2i128` to shuffle the qword you want to replace into the low lane, `pinsrq` (*not* `vpinsrq`), then `vpermq` to put it back in the right order.  That's all shuffle uops, and `pinsrq` is 2 uops.  (And causes an SSE/AVX transition stall on Haswell, but not Skylake).  Plus all those operations are part of a dependency chain for the register you're modifying, unlike setting up a value in another register and blending.