# Move an int64_t to the high quadwords of an AVX2 __m256i vector

Tags: c++, x86-64, simd, intrinsics, avx2

This question is similar to [1]. However I didn't quite understand how it addressed inserting to high quadwords of a ymm using a GPR. Additionally I want the operation not use any intermediate memory accesses.

Can it be done with AVX2 or below (I don't have AVX512)?

[1] [How to move double in %rax into particular qword position on %ymm or %zmm? (Kaby Lake or later)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309909/how-to-move-double-in-rax-into-particular-qword-position-on-ymm-or-zmm-kaby)

Comment: updated my answer with intrinsics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer [on the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309909/how-to-move-double-in-rax-into-particular-qword-position-on-ymm-or-zmm-kaby) didn't show a way to do that because it can't be done very efficiently without AVX512F for a masked broadcast (`vpbroadcastq zmm0{k1}, rax`).  But it's actually not all that bad using a scratch register, about the same cost as a `vpinsrq` + an immediate blend.

(On Intel, 3 uops total. 2 uops for port 5 (vmovq + broadcast), and an immediate blend that can run on any port. 
 See https://agner.org/optimize/).

I updated my answer there with asm for this.  In C++ with Intel's intrinsics, you'd do something like:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// integer version.  An FP version would still use _mm256_set1_epi64x, then a cast
template<unsigned elem>
static inline
__m256i merge_epi64(__m256i v, int64_t newval)
{
    static_assert(elem <= 3, "a __m256i only has 4 qword elements");

    __m256i splat = _mm256_set1_epi64x(newval);

    constexpr unsigned dword_blendmask = 0b11 << (elem*2);  // vpblendd uses 2 bits per qword
    return  _mm256_blend_epi32(v, splat, dword_blendmask);
}
```

Clang compiles this nearly perfectly efficiently for all 4 possible element positions, which really shows off how nice its shuffle optimizer is.  It takes advantage of all the special cases.  And as a bonus, it comments its asm to show you which elements come from where in blends and shuffles.

**[From the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Cunsigned+elem%3E%0Astatic+inline%0A__m256i+merge_epi64(__m256i+v,+int64_t+newval)%0A%7B%0A++++static_assert(elem+%3C%3D+3,+%22a+__m256i+only+has+4+qword+elements%22)%3B%0A++++__m256i+splat+%3D+_mm256_set1_epi64x(newval)%3B%0A%0A++++constexpr+unsigned+dword_blendmask+%3D+0b11+%3C%3C+(elem*2)%3B++//+vpblendd+uses+2+bits+per+qword%0A++++return++_mm256_blend_epi32(v,+splat,+dword_blendmask)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+test+functions%0A__m256i+merge3(__m256i+v,+int64_t+newval)+%7B%0A++++return+merge_epi64%3C3%3E(v,+newval)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__m256i+merge2(__m256i+v,+int64_t+newval)+%7B%0A++++return+merge_epi64%3C2%3E(v,+newval)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__m256i+merge1(__m256i+v,+int64_t+newval)+%7B%0A++++return+merge_epi64%3C1%3E(v,+newval)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__m256i+merge0(__m256i+v,+int64_t+newval)+%7B%0A++++return+merge_epi64%3C0%3E(v,+newval)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.06327601492114,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.48462940134176,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B17+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:30.452094583737093,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_16_x64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Ox+-arch:AVX2+-Gv',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x64+msvc+v19.16+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:30.452094583737093,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**, some test functions to see what happens with args in regs.

```
__m256i merge3(__m256i v, int64_t newval) {
    return merge_epi64<3> (v, newval);
}
// and so on for 2..0
```

```
# clang7.0 -O3 -march=haswell
merge3(long long __vector(4), long):
    vmovq   xmm1, rdi
    vpbroadcastq    ymm1, xmm1
    vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 192 # ymm0 = ymm0[0,1,2,3,4,5],ymm1[6,7]
                      # 192 = 0xC0 = 0b11000000
    ret

merge2(long long __vector(4), long):
    vmovq   xmm1, rdi
    vinserti128     ymm1, ymm0, xmm1, 1          # Runs on more ports than vbroadcast on AMD Ryzen
        #  But it introduced a dependency on  v (ymm0) before the blend for no reason, for the low half of ymm1.  Could have used xmm1, xmm1.
    vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 48 # ymm0 = ymm0[0,1,2,3],ymm1[4,5],ymm0[6,7]
    ret

merge1(long long __vector(4), long):
    vmovq   xmm1, rdi
    vpbroadcastq    xmm1, xmm1           # only an *XMM* broadcast, 1c latency instead of 3.
    vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 12 # ymm0 = ymm0[0,1],ymm1[2,3],ymm0[4,5,6,7]
    ret

merge0(long long __vector(4), long):
    vmovq   xmm1, rdi
           # broadcast optimized away, newval is already in the low element
    vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 3 # ymm0 = ymm1[0,1],ymm0[2,3,4,5,6,7]
    ret
```

Other compilers blindly broadcast to the full YMM and then blend, even for elem=0.  **You can specialize the template, or add `if()` conditions in the template that will optimize away.**  e.g. `splat = (elem?) set1() : v;` to save the broadcast for elem==0.  You could capture the other optimizations, too, if you wanted.

---

GCC 8.x and earlier use a normally-bad way of broadcasting the integer: they store/reload.  This avoids using any ALU shuffle ports because broadcast-loads are free on Intel CPUs, but it introduces store-forwarding latency into the chain from the integer to the final vector result.

This is fixed in current trunk for gcc9, but I don't know if there's a workaround to get non-silly code-gen with earlier gcc.  Normally `-march=<an intel uarch>` favours ALU instead of store/reload for integer -> vector and vice versa, but in this case the cost model still picks store/reload with `-march=haswell`.

```
# gcc8.2 -O3 -march=haswell
merge0(long long __vector(4), long):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    and     rsp, -32          # align the stack even though no YMM is spilled/loaded
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-8], rdi
    vpbroadcastq    ymm1, QWORD PTR [rsp-8]   # 1 uop on Intel
    vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 3
    leave
    ret

; GCC trunk: g++ (GCC-Explorer-Build) 9.0.0 20190103 (experimental)
; MSVC and ICC do this, too.  (For MSVC, make sure to compile with -arch:AVX2)
merge0(long long __vector(4), long):
    vmovq   xmm2, rdi
    vpbroadcastq    ymm1, xmm2
    vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1, 3
    ret
```

---

**For a runtime-variable element position**, the shuffle still works but you'd have to create a blend mask vector with the high bit set in the right element.  e.g. with a `vpmovsxbq` load from `mask[3-elem]` in `alignas(8) int8_t mask[] = { 0,0,0,-1,0,0,0 };`.  But `vpblendvb` or `vblendvpd` is slower than an immediate blend, especially on Haswell, so avoid that if possible.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed answer. I have one follow up question. For low order two elements what's the advantage of using this approach over pinsrq?

Comment: @budchanchao: `vpinsrq` would zero the high 2 elements.  `pinsrq` would cause an SSE/AVX stall on Haswell.  Non-VEX `pinsrq` for element 1 of a YMM might be optimal on Skylake (and on AMD and Xeon Phi), but you'll never get a compiler to emit that without inline asm.  For element 0, `vmovq` + `vpblendd` has better execution port pressure: 1p5 + 1p015 instead of 2p5 for `pinsrq xmm0, rax, 0`.