# Extract 8 bit integer from __m512i data type (AVX-512)

Tags: c, vectorization, intrinsics, avx512

Could not find equivalent of

```c
int _mm_extract_epi8 (__m128i a, const int imm8)
int _mm256_extract_epi8 (__m256i a, const int index)
```

in the AVX-512 instruction set.

What is the best way to extract an 8 bit integer from `__m512i` variable from specified position?

Comment: You could store the whole thing in an array with _mm512_storeu_epi8() and then pick out the index you want, but I guess you probably know that already. I don't think there is an equivalent intrinsic to those shown.

Comment: Do you need this exactly once, or multiple times in a hot loop? Is the index always known at compile time?

Comment: With `index` known at compiletime this should work: `_mm_extract_epi8(_mm512_extracti32x4_epi32(a, index >> 4), index & 0xf)`. Storing and reading as suggested by @SimonGoater is probably simpler (and also works with dynamic indexes).

Comment: Note that `_mm256_extract_epi8` is not a single machine instruction (except for `index = [0..3]`).  There's no `vpextrb` encoding with a YMM register, only XMM.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pextrb:pextrd:pextrq)

Comment: Sometimes worth considering is [`vpcompressb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpcompressb:vcompressw) with `1ULL<<index` as the mask, but then you'd still need a `vmovd` to get it into an integer register.  Or maybe `vpermb` if you have it (maybe with zero-masking to allow just `vmovd`) for a runtime-variable index.  Related for 16 and 32-bit elements: [How to implement 16 and 32 bit integer insert and extract operations with AVX-512?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58303958) - merge-masked broadcast is good for insert.  As @chtz says, if you want multiple bytes, store to an array.

Comment: @chtz, I need this in for loop, but positions are compile time constants. Your solution involves two intrinsics with latency 3 both (according to Intel intrinsics guide), and SimonGoater solution involves one but with latency 6. However i dont know if it is correct way to make conclusions about efficiency. Does that mean they are identical? Or knowing bytes indexes at compile time should somehow make your solution faster?

Comment: @KaraUL To make any conclusion about efficiency you need to show the context where you need this. Maybe you can avoid that operation all-together.