# How can I write rax register to a quadword element of AVX512 register zmm26?

Tags: x86-64, simd, avx512

This question is the inverse of [How can I write a QuadWord from AVX512 register zmm26 to the rax register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893523/how-can-i-write-a-quadword-from-avx512-register-zmm26-to-the-rax-register). In addition I have the requirement of not going to memory for intermediate storage. Is that possible? I want to be able to individually write each quadword element of zmm15-zmm31.

Comment: The question you linked contains your answer right in the question! `vpbroadcastq zmm26{k5}{z},rax` Use merge-masking instead of zero-masking, like `vpbroadcastq zmm26{k5}, rax`, if you want to merge into an existing register.